# JBoss logs Postgres driver is "non-JDBC-compliant"

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jboss

I wired my `JBoss` server into a new `Postgres` database.

In standalone.xml:

```
<driver name="postgresql" module="com.postgresql.pgjdbc">
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

In module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.postgresql.pgjdbc">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

When starting JBoss, I get the following log entry:

```
10:49:57,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.3)
```

The driver does seem to connect and work.  What are the effects of this non-compliance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According this JBoss forum entry none: [Why is my JDBC4-compliant driver loaded as "non-JDBC-compliant"?](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/173772)

> Because `org.postgresql.Driver#jdbcCompliant()` returns false. So you
>   can ignore that for now, and I'm sure that the PostgreSQL JDBC people
>   would like code contributions

And source code:

```
 /**
* Report whether the driver is a genuine JDBC compliant driver. A
* driver may only report "true" here if it passes the JDBC compliance
* tests, otherwise it is required to return false. JDBC compliance
* requires full support for the JDBC API and full support for SQL 92
* Entry Level.
*
* <p>For PostgreSQL, this is not yet possible, as we are not SQL92
* compliant (yet).
*/
public boolean jdbcCompliant()
{
    return false;
}
```

https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/REL9_3_1102/org/postgresql/Driver.java.in

This is part of the TODO List http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/todo.html#Compliance