# Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jboss

On NetBeans, my project runs with no errors, but when I put it on a JBoss server, I get this error:

> 18:54:40,111 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.3) 18:54:40,154 INFO [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /PrjX 18:54:40,173 INFO [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "PrjX_V2.war"

My code:

```
public Connection openConPG(){
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://[IP]:[PORTA]/[DATA_BASE]","[LOG]","[PASS]");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Projeto PrjX, classe Dao, método conexaoPostgres, erro: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return con;
}
```

I have never used Postgres with Java before so I don't have any idea what I can do to resolve this.

```
postgres driver: postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc41.jar
```

Can someone help?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108923/jboss-logs-postgres-driver-is-non-jdbc-compliant

Comment: in my case don't resolve, because next that error I get this:

18:56:14,813 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 4) JBAS014122: Error during retrying timeout for timer: [id=c7a5c2c9-2b6c-49d8-956a-f831ebab53c3 timedObjectId=PrjX_V2.PrjX_V2.CargaDados auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@35d07654 initialExpiration=Wed May 11 06:00:00 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Wed May 11 18:58:00 BRT 2016 timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBException: Unexpected Error